# Is it possible to configure apt so that the output of apt update does not list kept back packages?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 22.04

This question concerns the infamous "The following packages have been kept back" message, however, I'm **not** asking how to (1) disable phased updates (I'd rather stick to the "standard" update cycle); or (2) manually install the kept back packages (I know that this is a bad practice). Rather, what I'm looking for is a way to configure `apt` so that the "summary message" returned when running `apt update` simply disregards the kept back packages (in particular, those kept back due to phased updates).

For example, just now, when running `sudo apt update`, I'm getting the following "bottom line" message:

```
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Following that, I'm running `sudo apt full-upgrade` just to discover that the two "upgradable" packages are actually kept back and the upgrade attempt is redundant:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libruby3.0 ruby3.0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Therefore, what I'm looking for is a way to configure apt so that the the aforementioned "bottom line" message of `apt update` would have "ignored" the kept back packages and report instead that there is nothing to upgrade (at the moment).

Any ideas? For the record, I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 although I guess that the question may be relevant to other Ubuntu releases as well.

**Clarification:**
What I'm asking for is already implemented in the GUI `Software Updater` tool (also in `Synaptic`), where the "status report" regarding the upgradable packages does not take the kept back packages into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the only workaround is to ignore the output (i.e. the last line) of:

```
# apt update
[...]
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

and instead use the output of:

```
# apt-get --dry-run  upgrade | grep 'upgraded\.$'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the `dry-run` option

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that apt repositories do not change immediately.
When new package is uploaded to the repository, it is needed the time to upload it's dependencies. In this time, package cannot be installed/upgraded.

You can't configure this behaviour.

Comment: I think that there may have been some misunderstanding with my question, please see the clarification I added.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not.You can not do what you asked.